# Cluster analysis - match cluster centroids to cluster center item names based on index value

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I completed a cluster analysis and am able to mark each 'Item' appropriately in my dataset as to what cluster it belongs to.

I also have a list of the index values of the cluster centers, called centroidList.

I am trying to take the values in the list of centroids and produce a column called cluster centroid that matches my index value to the 'Item' value and then populates that 'Item' value, but am not clear how to proceed with this in R.

I tried doing some if/then statements, but didn't have much luck.

Any pointers?

```
Items <-c("ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO","PQR","STU","VWX")
Cluster <-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)

df <- data.frame(Items,Cluster)
df

centroidList <-c(1,5,7) #These represent the index of the cluster centers
```

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpNqv.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A reproducible example would help. Have a look at [mre] and [ask] for some helpful guidance.

Comment: @Peter sorry about that. I just updated it. I include a screenshot of what my end goal would look like. Hope this is more useful for the community.

Comment: Thanks and I hope that the answer is what you expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you would like the centroid entry to be the name of the cluster, so:

```
Items <-c("ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO","PQR","STU","VWX")
Cluster <-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)

df <- data.frame(Items,Cluster)

centroidList <-c(1,5,7)
centroidNames = df$Items[centroidList]
names(centroidNames) = unique(Cluster)

df[["Cluster Centroid"]] = centroidNames[as.character(df$Cluster)]
df

 Items Cluster Cluster Centroid
1   ABC       1              ABC
2   DEF       1              ABC
3   GHI       1              ABC
4   JKL       2              MNO
5   MNO       2              MNO
6   PQR       2              MNO
7   STU       3              STU
8   VWX       3              STU
```

I think much better if you ask it with a real life dataset, for example:

```
library(cluster)
data = data.frame(iris[,1:4])
data$Items = paste0("data",1:nrow(data))
clus = pam(data[,-5],3)
data$Cluster = clus$clustering
```

We get the centroid list like this, which corresponds to cluster 1,2 and 3:

```
centroidList = data$clus$id.med
centroidNames = data$Items[data$clus$id.med]
```

In this case, I can simply call it out in the same order because the cluster is numeric:

```
df[["Cluster Centroid"]] = centroidNames[data$Cluster]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you may be after...

```r
library(dplyr)
```

create a mapping dataframe

```
df_cl_map <- data.frame(centroidList, Cluster = 1:4)
```

simply carry out a left join to map the centroidList to the clusters.

Then create a new variable: `Cluster Centroid` by concatenating or `paste0` the text "Item" and the contents of `centroidList` with the `dplyr::mutate` function.

```
df %>% 
  left_join(df_cl_map) %>% 
  mutate(`Cluster Centroid` = paste0("Item", centroidList)) %>% 
  select(-centroidList)

#> Joining, by = "Cluster"
#>     Items Cluster Cluster Centroid
#> 1   Item1       1            Item1
#> 2   Item2       1            Item1
#> 3   Item3       1            Item1
#> 4   Item4       2            Item5
#> 5   Item5       2            Item5
#> 6   Item6       2            Item5
#> 7   Item7       3            Item7
#> 8   Item8       3            Item7
#> 9   Item9       4           Item10
#> 10 Item10       4           Item10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Peter. What exactly is happening on the 'mutate' line? I am not quite clear what is happening there.

Comment: Does the added commentary in the answer make sense?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is concatenating the information. Perhaps my data example wasn't as clear as it should have been.

Comment: I really need to do a match based on the index value. Are you able to share an example that doesn't require a concatenation of 'Item' and the value associated with my centroid list, but rather that uses my index (1:10) ? Please also assume that my items are not always going to follow the same pattern Item1, Item2, etc.

Comment: To be clear, your solution functions. But in my actual data set (contains private information I can't post here) I can't recreate it because the link between the look up item isn't as straight forward.

Comment: Chris the code is based on your index list: object `centroidList`. `centroidList` is used in the "mapping" dataframe `df_cl_map` to map with `Cluster` IDs. The concatenation with "Item" flows after the mapping has been carried out. I have removed the mapping column `centroidList` as it is not displayed in your expected table image.

Comment: If the link is more complex that is fine, you should replicate the complexity in your question using anonymised data. One can only answer what has been asked!

Comment: Yes, this is really my own fault. I was able to update my example to better reflect my use case. You have already done so much here, but if you could, I would much appreciate any other insight you have here.

Comment: Chris I suggest you ask this as another question. Replace the information you had before for this question: at least that is resolved. I think you new expected output is substantively different  and there is an other answer already based on your original question. No one will think the worse of it and you might even want to accept an answer on your original question.

Comment: Peter, much appreciate all your help. By the time I got here, someone else answered. Thanks for you advice and for showing me the ropes here...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very base R solution:

```r
unsplit(
  lapply(split(df, Cluster), 
         function(x) cbind(x, `Cluster Centroid`=intersect(paste0("Item", centroidList), x$Items))
         ), Cluster)
#>     Items Cluster Cluster Centroid
#> 1   Item1       1            Item1
#> 2   Item2       1            Item1
#> 3   Item3       1            Item1
#> 4   Item4       2            Item5
#> 5   Item5       2            Item5
#> 6   Item6       2            Item5
#> 7   Item7       3            Item7
#> 8   Item8       3            Item7
#> 9   Item9       4           Item10
#> 10 Item10       4           Item10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>